# Unable to Port Objective-C code to C#

Tags: c#, objective-c, port

I'm trying to port this objective-c code to c# with no success...

```
IMP imp = imp_implementationWithBlock(^void(id me, void* arg0, BOOL arg1, BOOL arg2, id arg3) {      
     ((void (*)(id, SEL, void*, BOOL, BOOL, id))originalImp)(me, sel, arg0, TRUE, arg2, arg3);
```

I have converted into this:

```
static Selector selector1;

[MonoNativeFunctionWrapper]
public delegate void OriginalDelegate(NSObject me, Selector sel, IntPtr arg0, bool arg1, bool arg2, NSObject arg3);

delegate void CaptureDelegate(NSObject me, IntPtr arg0, bool arg1, bool arg2, NSObject arg3);

[MonoPInvokeCallback(typeof(CaptureDelegate))]
static void MyCapture(NSObject me, IntPtr arg0, bool arg1, bool arg2, NSObject arg3)
{
  OriginalDelegate del = (OriginalDelegate)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(_original,   typeof(OriginalDelegate));
  del(me, selector1, arg0, true, arg2, arg3);
}
```

The code compiles correctly. The problem is very localized in:

**(me, selector1, arg0, true, arg2, arg3),  and specifically in the selector1 parameter. This call executes the delegate OriginalDelegate.
The error that occurs at runtime is:**

```
Type ObjCRuntime.Selector which is passed to unmanaged code must have a StructLayout attribute.
```

and it tells me that the Selector object must have the StructAttribute attribute defined. ????

Could anyone give us a hand ?

Thank you.

EDIT: I've added Selector1 declaration, also If I try to Change type `Selector to IntPtr` then I've the following error:

```
Objective-C exception thrown.Name: NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: -_NSMallocBlock__ _stopAssistingNode]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x12ff844d0
Native stack trace:
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000011465e12b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001153fcf41 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001146df024 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:]*- + 132
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001145e0f78 ___forwarding___ + 1432
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001145e0958 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   WebKit                              0x00000001072de47e -[WKContentView(WKInteraction) _startAssistingNode:userIsInteracting:blurPreviousNode:userObject:] + 291
    6   ???                                 0x000000013562b176 0x0 + 5190627702
```

Thanks again!

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: See msdn : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Where is `selector1` coming from? Is it a field? Should you be passing it's Handle as an IntPtr?

Comment: I've updated/edited my question responding to you: @JonathonChase that you

Comment: @CarLoOSX I think the Delegate declaration needs the type of selector to be `IntPtr`, and then you pass in `selector1.Handle`.

Comment: @JonathonChase unfortunately I have already tried this ... :( The error that it gives me is the one that I've  added at the end of the question. Any other idea ? Thank you very much :D

Comment: @CarLoOSX You say "also If I try to Change type `Selector` to `IntPtr`". Where did you change this? On the field, or in the delegate?

Comment: The call I've tried is this:                                                                              static Selector selector1;
[MonoNativeFunctionWrapper]
public delegate void OriginalDelegate(NSObject me, IntPtr sel, IntPtr arg0, bool arg1, bool arg2, NSObject arg3);

In MyCapture
  del(me, selector1.Handle, arg0, true, arg2, arg3);